# MySQL fabric server error when adding group

Tags: mysql, mysql-fabric

```
Fabric : 10.101.90.5
Master : 10.101.90.6
Slave: 10.101.90.7
```

I add the slave to the group and I get the below error:

```
mysqlfabric group add mygroup 10.101.90.7
Password for admin: 
Fabric UUID: 5calable-a007-feed-food-cab3fe13249e
Time-to-live: 1
ServerError: Error accessing server(10.101.90.7): 
2003: Cannot connect to MySQL server on '10.101.90.7:3306'(113 No route to host)
```

Does anyone know why this has happened? How can I solve it?

Comment: A firewall preventing access maybe?

Comment: Your hint solved my problem. Nice...